# Undefined en función javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo una función en la cual hago lectura de un archivo json, donde tengo una lista con usuarios, la recorro y comparo si el id de la lista es igual al userid con lo cual obtener el nombre de usuario, este pedazo de codigo corresponde a un aplicación de chat y la funcion es para obtener el nombre y poder mandarlo al usuario que recibe los mensajes y viceversa, aquí esta el código :

```js
function obtenerNombreUsuario(id){   
  $.getJSON("friends-list.json", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        if(i === id){
          return field;
        }else{
          return "";
        }
      });
   }); 
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde se define la función? El error lo recibes cuando se llama a la misma, ¿podrías añadir la parte del código en la que se hace esa llamada?

Comment: aquí se hace la llamada...---> nnUser = obtenerNombreUsuario(userId);

Comment: `getJSON` es una función asíncrona (inicialmente), no puedes devolver un valor y asignarlo a una variable. Para ello deberías hacerla asíncrona (algo no recomendado). Lo mejor sería que el código que depende del resultado de `getJSON` se mueva dentro de la función de resultado

Comment: en otro archivo lo utilizo y lo paso a un alerte y ahí si me arroja el resultoado... no se me ocurre otra manera de manejar la lista de usuarios ya que estan en ubicaciones diferentes o archivos diferentes...

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que deberias pasar un `callback` a la funcion para que continue la ejecucion luego que devuelva una respuesta el `$.getJSON`

```
function xxFunction(){

    obtenerNombreUsuario(userId, callbackFunc); 

}

function callbackFunc(friend){

    nnUser = friend;

    //codigo 
}

function obtenerNombreUsuario(id, callback){   
  $.getJSON("friends-list.json", function(data){
      var result = "";
      $.each(data, function(i, field){
        if(i === id){
          result = field;
        }
      });
      callback(result);
   }); 
}
```

Como veras el proceso se parte en dos, la priemr funcion invoca a la funcion que buscara en el json, y al encontrar una respuesta invocara el callback para continuar con el resto del codigo

Comment: La línea `var result=""`pisa el resultado del getJSON

Comment: si es verdad use el mismo nombre que la variable definida en el $.getJSON() pero edite el codigo para solucionarlo

Comment: Joya!! Buena respuesta por cierto